Cannot hear sound through headphone with Ubuntu 22.04 on certain machine

this question is reposted, and i also find the similar question with no answer from here: Ubuntu 22.04: No Audio from Wired Headphones, Detected as 'USB Audio' in Sound Settings

I installed Ubuntu on a Samsung T7 SSD (just "Linux to go"), and I have 2 machines (a laptop and a desktop both with Windows 10 on their SSDs). The Linux kernel version is 5.19.0-50-generic, and using linux-modules-5.19.0-50-generic
Here's the condition of my headphones:



mach \ os
ubuntu22.04
win10




laptop
works well
works well


desktop
headphone and output detected, but can't here sound
works well



I examined the situation of "Ubuntu 22.04 on my desktop":

settings - sound output can detect the headphones "Headphone USB Audio" (aux interface but USB Audio). P.S. and I can hear sound through "Speakers USB Audio"
pavucontrol can see the sound output bar dance when playing a video.

